# Prevent exit from DllMain with dll hijacking in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

Hi i'm testing dll hijacking scenario for the educational purpose and i have problem when DllMain loaded i want to create something that keeps my method (Thread) running but the problem is even if i create a new thread still when DllMain reaches at the end my thread killed with it !
if i do something like WaitForSingleObject or while (1) {} it causes the deadlock of course

Also i want to prevent the Main Process (executable file) to exit ! because when the applications loads all modules after that it close him self ! and that's not what i want ! i want to keep the application running . as long as the application is running my thread is live

any thoughts or advise ?

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LiveBackgroundListenerFunction, 0, 0, 0);
    }

//while (1) {} #DeadLock !!!
//WaitForSingleObject(hdl, 100); #DeadLock !!!
    
return TRUE;

void LiveBackgroundListenerFunction()
{
  While(1)
  {
    Sleep(5000);
    //Do Somthing......

  }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing in the posted code will close the thread - please include `LiveBackgroundListenerFunction` in the question.  Note that doing almost anything even in a separate thread is not recommended until [`DllMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) has released the loader lock.

Comment: @RichardCritten this method is abstraction of what i need it ! imaging a while(true) with sleep(5000) thats all

Comment: @RichardCritten How can i create a live thread after loader lock??

Comment: `CreateThread` is ok, it's the contents of the created thread that need to be careful.

Comment: A side note: in C++ it is better to use `std::thread`.

Comment: @RichardCritten I should point that , i want to prevent the Main Process (executable file)
to exit ! because when the applications loads all modules after that it close him self !
and that's not what i want ! i want to keep the application running . as long as the application is running my thread is live and working

Comment: @andrewlockwood: You can't really prevent the application from calling `ExitProcess`. This includes cases where `ExirProcess` is called by the application runtime, e.g. because its `main()` function returned. And even if you could, the application runtime may have run global dtors etc. so there's really nothing left that can reasonably run.

Comment: @MSalters I dont want to get in way of [ExitProcess] ! i just want to keep the application  busy through my dll

Comment: @andrewlockwood: I suspect part of the problem might be because you misunderstand how threads work. Your thread won't be killed when `DllMain` returns, so we have to speculate a bit about what does kill your thread. You may want to create a simple example where you hijack Notepad.EXE, just to get a hang of it.

Comment: @MSalters You are absolutely right my friend. the main process cause my thread to get killed because the target application was a simple windows service that runs for couple of seconds  and that's it. do you think i can find exit method in main process and try to hook it for preventing the exit functionality ?

Comment: @andrewlockwood: Windows Service? That's even less possible. Even if you could delay it, Windows will *kill* that service after 30 seconds. That's not from inside you process, that's a hard kill from the outside.